# The data is not set accordingly to their age

Tags: mysql

SELECT * FROM records

BEGIN

DECLARE @Age int ;
DECLARE @Level varchar(15);

WHILE  (@Age = 14 AND @Age =25)

IF @Age >= 14 AND @Age <=16

BEGIN

SET @Age = 'FRESHMEN';

END

ELSE IF @Age >=17 AND @Age <= 19

BEGIN

SET @Level ='SOPHOMORE';

END

ELSE IF @Age >= 20 AND @Age <=22

BEGIN

SET @Level ='JUNIOR';

END

ELSE IF @Age >=23 AND @Age <=25

BEGIN

SET @Level = 'SENIOR';

END

ELSE

BEGIN
SET @Level = 'UNKNOWN'

END

END

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tbKWE.png) this is the data

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8HkNj.png) this should be the output

Comment: You should explain what you want to do.  But given that `@age` is never initialized, it is not surprising that this does nothing useful.

Comment: good day sir  i edit and put the pictures of the data and the output ,

Comment: Good day sir im new to my sql i share the pictures of the data and the right output

Comment: You should give a test case and paste text instead of screenshots